# How to use Value in the python implementation of protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protoc, protobuf-python

I have a proto file defined as:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

package generic.name;

message Message {
  uint32 increment = 1;
  google.protobuf.Value payload = 2;
}
```

I have figured out how to make this work if I swap the payload type from `Value` for `Struct`:

```py
 struct = Struct()
 struct.update({"a": 1})
 msg = Message(payload=struct, increment=1)
```

However I cannot work out how to use the `Value` type in python. The python documentation for the protobuf `Value` field seems lacking compared to the other languages. Ultimately, all I want is to be able to have the `payload` data structure able to take a few different types (strings, ints, none, dict). What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example:

```py
from foo_pb2 import Bar

from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Struct


bar = Bar()

bar.payload.string_value="Freddie"

print(bar)
print(bar.SerializeToString())

bar.payload.bool_value=True

print(bar)
print(bar.SerializeToString())

# No need to initialize the Struct
bar.payload.struct_value.update({"foo":"bar"})
bar.payload.struct_value["baz"]=5

print(bar)
print(bar.SerializeToString())
```